# Make unlimited versions of a dict, same keys, different values

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dictionary, how can I take the keys, and allow a user to make unlimited versions of it with different values for each key?

Comment: This is surely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) if I've ever seen one

Comment: sorry everyone, hopefully I have made my question better :)

Comment: I bet `dict.copy` would be useful here.

Comment: If it has different values, why call it a copy? Where do the values come from? *"There would be no limit on the amount of dictionary copies the user could make"* - subject to RAM, presumably...

Comment: Removed some cruft. Shortened the lengthy title a bit. clarified language a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my_keys = ["Hello", "World"]
my_values1 = ["Why", "that"]

my_dict1 = dict(zip(my_keys, my_values1))

my_dict2 = dict.fromkeys(my_dict1.keys())
```

Variant 1 allows simple construction of any dict from both: a list of keys and values, while my_dict2 presents a varaint to create an "empty" (all values are `None` dict from an existing. You can also mix both (I leave that as an exercise;-).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`dict.fromkeys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) method:

```
def copy_keys(your_dict=None):
    if your_dict != None:
        return dict.fromkeys(your_dict.keys())
    else:
        return dict()
```

```
blah = dict((('blah',1),('haha',2)))
>>>blah
{'blah': 1, 'haha': 2}
```

```
>>> copy_keys(blah)
{'blah': None, 'haha': None}
```

My example function initalizes the values as `None` but you can easily adapt it to insert your own values by passing the `value` parameter to the `.fromkeys(seq[,value])` method.

Comment: Why would you use an interator in-between? keys already returns a view object.